# How to know this integration? Is it possible to evaluate the integral??

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I want to evaluate the integration.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{2x}{N}} \bigl( \sum_{r=0}^N \frac{(1-N)_r}{r!(r+1)!}x^{r+1} \bigr)^2 dx $$

$N$ is the natural number. And

$$
(1-N)_r=(1-N)(2-N)(3-N)\cdots(r-N) .
$$

I expanded the integrand like below

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-2x}{N}}\bigl( x + \frac{1-N}{1!2!}x^2 +\frac{(1-N)(2-N)}{2!3!}x^3+\cdots \bigr)^2dx $$

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: What's the context of this?

Comment: I consider wave function with one-dimensional Coulomb potential and it should be normalized. According to this paper(http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.1975232), the parameter $b_0$ in A7 is defined by the integral. I have to know $b_0$ with general $N$. This is why I try to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright well,
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2x/N}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{N}\frac{(1-N)_r}{r!(r+1)!}x^{r+1}\right)^2 dx &= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-2x/N}\sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N}\frac{(1-N)_i (1-N)_j}{i!j!(i+1)!(j+1)!}x^{i+j+2}dx \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N}\frac{(1-N)_i (1-N)_j}{i!j!(i+1)!(j+1)!}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2x/N}x^{i+j+2}dx
\end{aligned}$$
From here to proceed we have that
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2x/N}x^{i+j+2}dx &= (N/2)^{i+j+3}\Gamma(i+j+3) \\
&= (N/2)^{i+j+3}(i+j+2)!
\end{aligned}$$
by a simple substitution of $2x/N\to t$ and the definition of the Gamma Function. Thus, calling the integral $I$, we continue
$$\begin{aligned}
I &= \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N}\frac{(1-N)_i (1-N)_j (i+j+2)!}{i!j!(i+1)!(j+1)!}\cdot\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^{i+j+3} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N}(-1)^{i+j}\binom{i+j+2}{i+1}\binom{N-1}{i}\binom{N-1}{j}\cdot\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^{i+j+3} \\
&= \left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^3\sum_{i=0}^{N}(-1)^i\binom{N-1}{i}\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^i (i+2){}_2 F_1(3+i,1-N;2;N/2)
\end{aligned}$$
I am still working on simplifying this, although I would be surprised to have any luck.

Comment: Still an excellent try. Perhaps a hypergeometric function falls out of here.

Comment: @SeanRoberson It almost simplifies down to the square of a hypergeometric function. It would if the term $(i+j+2)!$ were not there.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your calculation.